# react HOC and losing reference to this

Tags: reactjs, react-native, this

I'm trying to understand and use HOC with react and redux.  I have the following setup.  I will have multiple buttons using the hoc and passing in their own onClick. and would like to know:

a. Is this a good usage of the HOC pattern?

b. with this setup inside of the render function of FooterButton, `this` references DesignatedWorkerGlobalScope and iconHeigh, iconWidth, and iconColor inside HomeButton become either undefined or unexpected values.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import { getColors, getStylesheet} from "../../styles/StyleManager";

const FooterButtonWrapper = (FooterButtonWrapped, onClick) => { 
    return class FooterButton extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                Theme: getStylesheet(),
                colors: getColors()
            }            
        }

        _onClick = () => {
            onClick(this.props.dispatch);
        }

        render() {            
            const { Theme, colors } = this.state;

            return(                
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onClick}>
                    <FooterButtonWrapped iconWidth={15} iconHeight={15}  iconColor={"white"}/>            
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({});


const composeFooterButton = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    FooterButtonWrapper 
);

export default composeFooterButton;
```

and then a button that uses it:

`import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { push as gotoRoute } from 'react-router-redux';

import { FooterButtonWrapper } from './';
import { Home } from '../../assets';


const HomeButton = ({iconHeight, iconWidth, iconColor}) => (

    <View>
        <Home width={ iconWidth } height={ iconHeight } color={ iconColor }/>   
        <View><Text>Home</Text></View>
    </View>
);

const _onClick = dispatch => {
    dispatch( gotoRoute( '/' ));
}

export default FooterButtonWrapper(HomeButton, _onClick);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens so, as you use

```
const composeFooterButton = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    FooterButtonWrapper 
);

export default composeFooterButton;
```

for HOC function instead of Component.

Both `compose` and `connect` can wrap your Component.
So your HOC could be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import { getColors, getStylesheet } from '../../styles/StyleManager';

export default function FooterButtonWrapper(FooterButtonWrapped, onClick) {
  class FooterButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        Theme: getStylesheet(),
        colors: getColors(),
      };
    }

    _onClick = () => {
      onClick(this.props.dispatch);
    };

    render() {
      const { Theme, colors } = this.state;

      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onClick}>
          <FooterButtonWrapped
            iconWidth={15}
            iconHeight={15}
            iconColor={'white'}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({});


  return connect(mapStateToProps)(FooterButton);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikita!  That worked.  So compose will return a function even if the last function it composes is the connect call?  I sort of thought this would return a Component in the end

Comment: @webhound  `connect` works with React.Component and returns their own instance of React.Component too. Compose works with functions: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/3f93d6bb21fd104263bc83da87bd2e113e82bd9f/src/compose.js So you got next structure: `<Connect(T)>< FooterButtonWrapper></Connect>`, but FooterButtonWrapper shouldn't be a Component,